# Best way to use Speech to text and Text to Speech in Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, text-to-speech, speech-to-text

I have found **[Text to Speech](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tts)**, but I also need **Speech to text**. Is there any way that Google offers it or an alternative to work with both?

Comment: Give a look at this API:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/SpeechRecognition

Answer (score 0):

Try [SpeechToTextJs](https://github.com/imalhasaranga/SpeechToTextJs)

which is a pure javascript solution I wrote, see the sample code below

```js
var speecht2text = new SpeechToText(function(){
   speecht2text.setIsContinous(true);
   speecht2text.setAllowInterimResults(true);
   speecht2text.setMaxAlternatives(20);

   var lang = speecht2text.getAllSupportedLanguages();
   speecht2text.setLanguage((lang[0]).key);  // english

   speecht2text.start();

   speecht2text.onEnd(function () {
    alert(speecht2text.getText());
   });

   setTimeout(function(){
    speecht2text.stop();
   },5000);
  },function () {
   alert("Browser Not Supported");
  });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/imalhasaranga/SpeechToTextJs/master/dist/SpeechToTextJs.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body  >
</body>
</html>
```